# 12.04 auditd will not record user login and logoff to audit.log

Tags: security, logging

Auditd only logs events of types `CWD`, `PATH` and `SYSCALL`.  It never seems to detect events of type `USER_LOGIN` for example.   I have enabled rules to catch these `login/logout` events but they do not seem to be detected correctly by `auditd`.  Running `aureport --failed` or `aureport --success` never produces any login or authentication related results even though there are multiple entries in the `faillog`. `wtmp` and `btmp` log files.  I do see entries in the `auth.log`, but I am trying to get these entries in one consolidated location like I have always been able to do with Redhat, and SuSe distro's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

audit, libaudit, libauparse0 and audispd-plugins versions all:  1:2.3.2-2ubuntu1

audit.rules (minimal for testing)

```
-D

-b 8192
-f 2

-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S adjtimex -S settimeofday -k time-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S adjtimex -S settimeofday -S stime -k time-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S clock_settime -k time-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S clock_settime -k time-change


-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity


-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S sethostname -S setdomainname -k system-locale
-a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S sethostname -S setdomainname -k system-locale
-w /etc/issue -p wa -k system-locale
-w /etc/issue.net -p wa -k system-locale
-w /etc/hosts -p wa -k system-locale
-w /etc/network -p wa -k system-locale


-w /var/log/faillog -p wa -k logins
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins
-w /var/log/tallylog -p wa -k logins

-w /var/run/utmp -p wa -k session
-w /var/log/wtmp -p wa -k session
-w /var/log/btmp -p wa -k session
```

auditd.conf

```
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_format = RAW
log_group = root
priority_boost = 4
flush = SYNC
freq = 0
num_logs = 0
disp_qos = lossy
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file = 5
max_log_file_action = KEEP_LOGS
space_left = 750
space_left_action = SYSLOG
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 500
admin_space_left_action = SYSLOG
disk_full_action = SYSLOG
disk_error_action = SYSLOG
##tcp_listen_port = 
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
```

faillog output

```
Login       Failures Maximum Latest                   On

test            1        0   03/21/15 21:31:10 -0400  /dev/pts/3
test2           2        0   03/21/15 22:42:09 -0400
```

/var/log/authlog (snippet)

```
Mar 21 20:51:11 U1 login[101526]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/3' FOR 'test2', Authentication failure
Mar 21 20:51:13 U1 login[101526]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/3' is not secure !
Mar 21 20:51:13 U1 login[101526]: pam_tally(login:auth): pam_get_uid; no such user
Mar 21 21:17:01 U1 CRON[109494]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 21 21:17:01 U1 CRON[109494]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 21 21:29:33 U1 login[112465]: pam_tally(login:auth): user test2 (1002) tally 5, deny 3
Mar 21 21:29:42 U1 login[112465]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=root uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/3 ruser= rhost=  user=test2
Mar 21 21:29:45 U1 login[112465]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/3' FOR 'test2', Authentication failure
Mar 21 21:30:37 U1 login[112471]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=root uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/3 ruser= rhost=  user=test2
Mar 21 21:30:40 U1 login[112471]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/3' FOR 'test2', Authentication failure
Mar 21 21:30:54 U1 login[112471]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user test2 by root(uid=0)
Mar 21 21:30:54 U1 login[112657]: 'test2' logged in  on '/dev/pts/3'
Mar 21 21:31:14 U1 su[112756]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=test2 uid=1002 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/3 ruser=test2 rhost=  user=test
Mar 21 21:31:16 U1 su[112756]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Mar 21 21:31:16 U1 su[112756]: FAILED su for test by test2
Mar 21 21:31:16 U1 su[112756]: - /dev/pts/3 test2:test
Mar 21 21:31:21 U1 login[112471]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user test2
Mar 21 22:42:02 U1 login[123946]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=root uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser= rhost=  user=test2
Mar 21 22:42:06 U1 login[123946]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/2' FOR 'test2', Authentication failure
Mar 21 22:42:14 U1 login[123946]: FAILED LOGIN (2) on '/dev/pts/2' FOR 'test2', Authentication failure
```

aureport output

```
Failed Summary Report
======================
Range of time in logs: 03/21/2015 20:26:48.495 - 03/21/2015 21:46:21.023
Selected time for report: 03/21/2015 20:26:48 - 03/21/2015 21:46:21.023
Number of changes in configuration: 0
Number of changes to accounts, groups, or roles: 0
Number of logins: 0
Number of failed logins: 0
Number of authentications: 0
Number of failed authentications: 0
Number of users: 0
Number of terminals: 0
Number of host names: 0
Number of executables: 0
Number of files: 0
Number of AVC's: 0
Number of MAC events: 0
Number of failed syscalls: 0
Number of anomaly events: 0
Number of responses to anomaly events: 0
Number of crypto events: 0
Number of keys: 0
Number of process IDs: 0
Number of events: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the identical problem running aureport on my 12.04 system. It looks like this is caused by an OS bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audit/+bug/1478087. 
"The bug is not in aureport or libaudit. aureport looks for AUDIT_USER_LOGIN events in the audit log but we're not generating them in login programs due to libaudit support not being enabled at build time or, in the case of lightdm, missing libaudit support.

Note that we are generating an AUDIT_LOGIN event from the kernel upon login but aureport and friends are looking for AUDIT_USER_LOGIN events from userspace."